# UILabels crashing my app

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring

So I don't know any way to draw text or strings but a UILabel. So I initialized the label, but it keeps crashing my app.

Here are the methods that initialize the labels and are causing the crash:

> -(void) setupScore{
>
> ```
> scoreLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
> scoreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(262, 250, 100, 40);
> [scoreLabel setText: scoreString];
>
> //normally you'll want a transparent background for your label
> scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 
>
> //you can use non-standard fonts
> [scoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size: 1.0f]];
>
> //change the label's text color
> scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>
> //add it to your view
> scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
> [self addSubview:scoreLabel]; }
> ```
>
> -(void) setupPausedLabel{
>
> ```
> pausedLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap To Resume"];
> pausedLabel.frame = CGRectMake(262, 250, 100, 40);
> [pausedLabel setText: @"Tap To Resume"];
>
> //normally you'll want a transparent background for your label
> pausedLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
>
> //you can use non-standard fonts
> [pausedLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size: 1.0f]];
>
> //change the label's text color
> pausedLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
>
> //add it to your view
> pausedLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
> [pausedLabel setHidden: YES];
> [self addSubview:pausedLabel]; }
> ```

Thanks for your help!

Comment: The details of the "crash" are _always_ important.  It's usually not not a crash, it's an _exception_ which has been _raised_.  What was the exception? What does the exception message complain about? And on what line does the exception get triggered?

Answer (score 2):

You are doing :

```
scoreLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
```

You should do :

```
scoreLabel = [[UILabel alloc] init];    // And release it somewhere
scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
```

and same for the pauseLabel.

Comment: Haha, I might have seen the question the moment it had been published ^^

Comment: Ok I did that, but now that label draws, but crashes when my gamestate changes from Menu to Gameplay (ie. the score is now adding up).

Comment: IS there possibly another way to draw NSStrings and integers?

Comment: use %@ to print an NSString and %d to print an integer

Answer (score 0):

You are initializing your label with a NSString class it should be a UILabel. Make sure you generate your string with the good formater: %d for integer and %@ for an NSString object. Check this [doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/Strings/Articles/formatSpecifiers.html) to find the appropriate specifier:

```
NSString* scoreString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
NSString* anotherString = @"Tap To Resume";
NSString* pausedString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", anotherString];
```

Answer (score 0):

You are wrong in your first line.

```
scoreLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];

scoreLabel=[[UILable alloc]init];
scoreLabel.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",score];
```

And Same Problem in NextMethod

```
pausedLabel = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap To Resume"];
```

It's not Right

```
    pausedLabel=[[UILable alloc]init];
pausedLable.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Tap To Resume"];
```

UILable text Property you are messing so it's give you crashing problem

Comment: I did that, and now it crashes later, when the label text changes (i.e. the score is adding). Is there another way to draw text and integers?

Comment: but it's working when i made this changes in your code.You are not write pausedLabel.text=@"String";

Comment: I fixed the code how everyone told me, but the app crashes when the score starts to change.

Comment: pls chech me where do you call method for label text changes.

Comment: -(void)drawScore{  
    [scoreLabel setText: scoreString];
}

Comment: That is the method that actually changes the UILabel's text.

Comment: I think you are call method in initWithCoder and allocate scoreLabel after this so it give you crashing problem.

Comment: Well the way my project is set up, everything is initialized in the initWithCoder function.

Comment: Is there another easier way to draw strings an integers?

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) setupScore{

 scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
scoreLabel.frame = CGRectMake(262, 250, 100, 40);
```

[scoreLabel setText: scoreString];

```
//normally you'll want a transparent background for your label
scoreLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor]; 

//you can use non-standard fonts
[scoreLabel setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"TimesNewRoman" size: 1.0f]];

//change the label's text color
scoreLabel.textColor = [UIColor whiteColor];

//add it to your view
scoreLabel.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(89.53);
[self.view addSubview:scoreLabel];
```

}

It's working fine I'm calling it in viewDidLoad

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
```

{
    [super viewDidLoad];

```
scoreLabel=[[UILabel alloc]init];

scoreString=[NSString stringWithString:@"1221"];

score=10;

[self setupScore];

scoreString=[NSString stringWithString:@"11"];


[self setupScore];

scoreString=[NSString stringWithString:@"333"];


[self setupScore];

[self setupScore];

scoreLabel.text=@"okey...";
```

}

Comment: But I'm not using viewDidLoad.

Comment: When do you call this method? Try [scoreString retain]; where do you set string. before calling method.

Comment: I call it in my init function, which is then passed to initWithCoder.

Comment: May be you are not alloc string before calling method .Which code i send you it's working .You are where do you call method . let check it you are allocate or retain scoreString before calling method.